# how do you get email data in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Why does this crash my android app whenever I attempt to run it / what is the best way to get email data into an android app?

The app itself only consists of a button to click - I have gotten the below code to work in eclipse and I am attempting to run it on a mobile phone and not an emulator so I am no longer getting a network error.

```
package com.example.marc.emailtest;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void buttonOnClick(View v){



        String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
        String StoreType = "pop3";
        String user = "******@gmail.com";// I purposefully hid these
        String password = "********";// I purposefully hid these

        try {
            //create properties field
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

            store.connect(host, user, password);

            //create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

            for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                Log.i("MainActivity1", "---------------------------------");
                Log.i("MainActivity1", "Email Number " + (i + 1));
                Log.i("MainActivity1", "Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                Log.i("MainActivity1", "From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                Log.i("MainActivity1", "Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

            }

            //close the store and folder objects
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("MainActivity1", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("MainActivity1", e.getMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("MainActivity1", e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the logcat]

Comment: Add the logCat.

Comment: Add the output of LogCat indeed, that would give an indication of what's wrong. I don't know if this is handled by the javax.mail package or not, but my first guess would be that you're trying to do network related things on the main thread, which is not allowed on Android.

Try to wrap it into an AsyncTask and see if that works.

Comment: logcat has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your `Log.i` calls has null as message.
Looking at your code, this will likely be in one of the `catch` blocks.

Try to log the errors like this:

```
Log.i("MainActivity1", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
```